AsyncIO how to make use of selectors
AsyncIO uses an event loop to pause and resume methods. For example, you can implement a simple corotine like this
import types

@types.coroutine
def wait(seconds: int) -> None:
    start_time = time.time()

    while time.time() - start_time < seconds:
        yield

This method will wait at least n seconds. But it is of course possible that it waits more than n seconds, since it will only continue when it is resumed, which will be on the next loop iteration.
You could do a similar thing if you wanted to create a request and continue once it was successful.
import socket
from socket import BlockingIOError

@types.coroutine
def request(url: str) -> None:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((url, 80))
    s.send(f'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: {url}\n\n'.encode())
    s.setblocking(False)

    response = b''
    while True:
        try:
            data = s.recv(1024)
            response += data
        except BlockingIOError:
            if response:
                break
            yield

This method will check each iteration to see if data can be retrieved, and if so, continue with the other tasks in the event loop.
I know that most modern operating systems provide a functionality to select all sockets that are ready. For example in the case of Linux this is epoll (which has a time complexity of O(1)).
My question now is how to use this with AsyncIO. It would be great to have the functionality to resume execution of the method (generator) only when the socket is really ready.
I have seen that asyncio exposes some socket methods like socket_connect. But I wasn't been able to find out if this uses selectors under the hood.
@types.coroutine
async def request(url: str) -> None:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.sock_connect(url, 80)
    ...


Based on the examples in your question I'm afraid you are going in wrong direction. Asyncio provides well-tested I/O functions. They are based on select/poll. You should use them.

I agree 100% with VPIB.  Your first example does not come close to being a substitute for asyncio.sleep(seconds): the only way to escape from its while loop is to iterate repeatedly, for example by calling its __next__ method.  This consumes CPU resources for no purpose.  Asyncio does not work that way; the routine is suspended while the event loop keeps track of when it is to be resumed.  Very little CPU resource is wasted.  Asyncio took years to develop, and is highly optimized.
